# Not switching to another screen after logo is finish kivy python

Tags: python, android, image, kivy, png

I have some issue with finding a path to the images i wanna use for logo.
Path looks fine for me anyway.
Another thing is after logo finish trying to load *.png files.
I fix switching screens, so one less to go.

Any idea to solve this issue or tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <ezgif-frame-001.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <ezgif-frame-002.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <ezgif-frame-003.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <ezgif-frame-004.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <ezgif-frame-005.png>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Not found <ezgif-frame-006.png>
etc...
```

here python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
import random
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import threading
from time import sleep
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class Main(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Numbers(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def start_process(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.process, daemon=True).start()

    def process(self):
        while True:
            global number
            print('process')
            num_list = ['null','four','three']
            number = random.choice(num_list)
            if number == 'null':
                self.ids.numb.text = number
            elif number == 'three':
                self.ids.numb.text = number
            elif number == 'four':
                self.ids.numb.text = number# set text on the main thread
            else:
                pass

    def set_text(self, dt):
        self.ids.numb.text = number


class Logo(Screen):
    def logoo(self):
        self.file_name = ['ezgif-frame-001.png','ezgif-frame-002.png','ezgif-frame-003.png','ezgif-frame-004.png','ezgif-frame-005.png','ezgif-frame-006.png','ezgif-frame-007.png','ezgif-frame-008.png','ezgif-frame-009.png','ezgif-frame-010.png','ezgif-frame-011.png','ezgif-frame-012.png','ezgif-frame-013.png','ezgif-frame-014.png','ezgif-frame-015.png','ezgif-frame-016.png','ezgif-frame-017.png','ezgif-frame-018.png','ezgif-frame-019.png']
    for i in self.file_name:
        sleep(0.07)
        self.filename = i
        self.image = Image(source=self.filename)


class NumbersApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


kv = Builder.load_file('temp.kv')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    NumbersApp().run()
```

Here is kv code:

```
Main:
    #I JUST SWOPE PLACES WITH Numbers and Logo and switching  
    #screens is working now.
    Numbers:
    Logo:


<Numbers>:

    number:numb
    cols:1
    RelativeLayout:
        Label:
            id: numb
            text: 'Te def'
            font_size: '15'
            hint_size: None, None
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.04, 'y': -0.4}
            color: 1,1,1,1
        Button:
            text: 'Start Process'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1}
            on_release: root.start_process()
<Logo>:
    RelativeLayout:
        Image:
            source: root.logoo()
            size: self.texture_size
```

I modify a bit a code, logo is loading but only logo so far.
also im tring put it into my code Clock.schedule. I really would like to understand why is it not working. Anyone can help please?

My current Error:

```
                line 29, in process
     self.ids.numb.text = number
 AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'ids'
```

new code:

```
from kivy.app import App
import random
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import threading
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial

class Main(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Numberss(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


    def start_process(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.process, daemon=True).start()

    def process(self):

        while True:
            global number
            print('process')
            num_list = ['null','four','three']
            number = random.choice(num_list)
            if number == 'null':
                self.ids.numb.text = number
            elif number == 'three':
                self.numb.text = number
            elif number == 'four':
                self.numb.text = number
            else:
                pass

    def set_text(self, dt):
        self.ids.numb.text = number


class NumbersApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(Numberss.process, 7)
        return kv


class Logo(Screen):
    pass



kv = Builder.load_file('temp.kv')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    NumbersApp().run()
```

KV:

```
Main:
    Logo:
    Numberss:

<Numberss>:
    name: 'number'
    number:numb
    cols:1
    RelativeLayout:
        Label:
            id: numb
            text: 'Te def'
            font_size: '15'
            hint_size: None, None
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.04, 'y': -0.4}
            color: 1,1,1,1
        Button:
            text: 'Start Process'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1}
            on_release: root.start_process()

<Logo>:
    name: 'logo'
    RelativeLayout:
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.0, 'y': 0.0}
        size_hint: (1, 1)
        Image:
            source: 'logos.zip'
            anim_delay: 0.07
            anim_loop: 1
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, instead of all the hassle, there's this android feature called "presplash" (more commonly known as splash screen) and I recommend you trying it out. Oh and by the way about your problem, I think it's because of the indentation of your `for` loop in the `Logo` class that is giving out an error, but it might not be the case

Comment: i just copy wrong way here this for loop, it's right indentation in my code. My mistake because I copy files to different folder i should, that's why i couldn't find *.png files.          but... this is  still not working, images are loading but screen is all black and after images are finish loaded program has started as expected.  By the way I read little about splash screen and for sure i will need spend more time studing current subject.